# Override touch-pad scrolling on Edge

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, microsoft-edge

It appears that when you are using `overflow: hidden` on Edge the event `mousewheel` no longer gets triggered when you use the touch-pad to scroll (middle button of mouse still works). This problem only appears when using Edge and Internet Explorer.

The following script logs the scrolling distances that should occur with each `mousewheel` event. (Works when using chrome and firefox).

```js
document.querySelector("#out").addEventListener("mousewheel", function(event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    if (event.deltaX || event.deltaY) {
      move(0, event.deltaX || event.deltaY);
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    return;
  }
  console.log(event.deltaY, event.deltaX);
  event.preventDefault();
}, {
  passive: false
});
```

```css
#out {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <div id="in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis tortor ultricies nibh mollis scelerisque. Proin eget mauris sollicitudin, eleifend lorem nec, aliquam justo. Pellentesque commodo ante nec finibus porta. Nam lobortis tempus ultrices. Ut ultrices, enim eget sodales eleifend, enim ipsum tincidunt nisl, ut tempor justo ante non nisi. Etiam ut ex non justo pellentesque posuere. Nulla sollicitudin massa viverra sapien congue, quis faucibus nisl aliquam. Duis ac fringilla eros. Vestibulum pretium, sem pulvinar consectetur ornare, urna justo vestibulum ligula, ullamcorper dignissim lectus velit quis turpis. Proin eu risus justo. Sed at nibh ac tortor rutrum mollis sagittis bibendum leo. Nunc feugiat mauris nec volutpat vestibulum. Phasellus ultricies, lacus sit amet posuere dapibus, nibh ligula pellentesque ligula, vitae congue massa ipsum sit amet velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris vel aliquet enim. Donec in lorem consequat, ullamcorper lectus sed, consectetur augue.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue that you could find [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7134034/). From the response of the Microsoft Edge Team in the issue tracker, we could see that the issue has been solved now by implementing **PTP Pointer Events** as outlined in [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/12/07/better-precision-touchpad-experience-ptp-pointer-events/).

You could use the Pointer Events like below:

> In HTML, add the touch-action CSS property to your target element to prevent the browser from executing its default touch behavior in response to gestures:

```
<canvas height=400 width=400 id="canvas" style="touch-action: none;"></canvas>
```

> In JavaScript, attach a Pointer Event listener to your target element. You can determine the type of pointer that caused the handler to be invoked using the pointerType property of the event object passed into the event listener callback:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('pointermove', function(event) {
    console.log('pointermove!');
});
```

For more information about Pointer Events, you could refer to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events/Using_Pointer_Events).

Comment: Isn't there a way keep the `touch-action: pinch-zoom` functionality for touch screens, will also overriding the scroll?

Comment: It seems that we only need to set the `touch-action` CSS property to `none` or other value than `auto`. If setting to `none`, you're telling the browser to not perform those browser-level actions on the element and instead trigger Pointer Events. Other values will allow you to continue some browser behaviors and then fire a subset of events.

Comment: I already had it set to `touch-action: pinch-zoom` since I wanted the `zoom-in` and `zoom-out` functionality. But the `pointermove` event wasn't getting fired.

Comment: You could try to set `touch-action: none` and refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events/Pinch_zoom_gestures) about using Pointer Events to detecting pinch and zoom gesture. You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124372/pointermove-event-not-working-with-touch-why-not/48254578#48254578) about `pointermove` not fired issue.

Comment: Even if I use `touch-action: none` and ignore the `zoom-in` and `zoom-out` functionality. There's still no way of getting the `deltaY` and `deltaX` values.

Comment: `deltaX` and `deltaY` is **WheelEvent** property, you can't get them in Pointer Events. [PointerEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent) has its own properties and inherits properties from [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent). You should choose the properties you need from them. Besides, I also find [this article](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-pointer-events-api-combining-touch-mouse-and-pen) helpful, you could also check it.

Comment: By `deltaX` and `deltaY` I mean the distances traveled on the x and y axis, but I can't know them, without knowing the coordinates of the start event. Is there a way to calculate them using `PointerEvent`?

Comment: I think there's not such a property equal to the `deltaX` or `deltaY` as the movement of fingers in a touch-pad is different from the mouse wheel. If you want to calculate the scroll distance, I think you could get the `screenX` and `screenY` when `pointerdown` fired and get the properties again when `pointerup` fired, then calculate the difference between them. This is my assumption and you could have a try if you think it make sense.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the existence of those events. This should fix my problem, thank you.