# "touchmove" event not working as expected in React

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, jsx, addeventlistener

I am building an app in NextJS. I am trying to create a window manager in which you can drag and resize panels.
Everything works well on desktop, but on mobile, the event listeners are not behaving I expected them to, and I don't know what the problem is.

When trying to drag a panels (which is a div in code), I use the onTouchStart and onTouchEnd events on the panels div to determine when the drag is started and ended. During the drag, I use the "touchmove" event on the browser window to check for movement and position the panel accordingly.

This works on desktop (using the "mousemove" event), but on mobile, the "touchmove" event only fires once, when I start the drag.

This does not happen if I try to drag on the rest of the screen (not on the panel div). I also tried to add a onTouchMove directly to the panel div, but this also does not work.
I suspect this has something to do with React rendering since in the touchmove event handler I change the state which causes the panel div to rerender, maybe?

You can see this for yourself on [the live app](https://dashwall.vercel.app/). Using the menu on the bottom right, add a widget, then enter Edit Mode. Dragging will work if you are on desktop, you can enter mobile mode using devtools.

Here is the code I use for the dragging logic:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const onMove = (clientX: number, clientY: number) => {
            if(!isEditMode || !draggingPanel) return
            
            // does some calculations, changes the state by calling
            // setGhostPanel, setIsDragInvalid, and replacePanel
        }

        const onMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => onMove(e.clientX, e.clientY)
        const onTouchMove = (e: TouchEvent) => onMove(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY)
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
        window.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
            window.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove)
        }
    }, [isEditMode, draggingPanel, dragStartPos, setIsDragInvalid])
```

And this is the panel div:

```js
                    <div
                        onMouseDown={(e) => onPanelMouseDown(panel, e)}
                        onTouchStart={(e) => onPanelTouchStart(panel, e)}
                        onDragStart={(e) => e.preventDefault()}

                        key={`panel${panel.uid}`}
                        className={styles.panel}
                        data-editing={draggingPanel?.uid == panel.uid || resizingPanel?.uid == panel.uid}
                        data-invalid={
                            ((draggingPanel?.uid == panel.uid) && isDragInvalid) ||
                            ((resizingPanel?.uid == panel.uid) && isResizeInvalid)
                        }
                        style={{
                            width: (panel.width * cellSize) - (cellMargin*2),
                            height: (panel.height * cellSize) - (cellMargin*2),
                            left: (panel.xPos * cellSize) + cellMargin,
                            top: (panel.yPos * cellSize) + cellMargin,
                        }}
                    >
                        <props.insidePanelComponent panel={panel}/>
                    </div>
```

You can also view the full source code on the [Github repository](https://github.com/itaypoo/dashwall)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be also having this problem, I got a solution from the top answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124372/pointermove-event-not-working-with-touch-why-not)

After a short period of time, the (mobile) browser will claim the pointermove event for "native" behavior like panning the page.

The designed, simple solution is to use the css property `touch-action` and set it to `none` on the container that has the event handler.

Also, I migrated to using pointermove since it covers both desktop and mobile. No need to use both mousemove and touchmove.